# Modify the loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote a script for retrieve a data from online json file and it's work great but the problem is when display the data that retrieved from json when the download complete and this take time and make the app boring, I need to modify the code to display data one by one sequence to show data once the customer run the app.
Note : I used assist script to download the json as a array.
This is my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System;

public class Demo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Serializable]
    public struct Data
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Desc;
        public float Price;
        public Sprite Icon;
        public string IconUrl;
    }

    bool check = false;
    Data[] allData;
    [SerializeField] Sprite defulticon;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(GetData());
        DrawUI();
    }

    void DrawUI()
    {
        GameObject Tamplets = transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
        GameObject g;
        int N = allData.Length;
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            g = Instantiate(Tamplets, transform); g.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Text>().text = allData[i].Name;     g.transform.GetChild(2).GetComponent<Text>().text = allData[i].Desc;     g.transform.GetChild(3).GetComponent<Text>().text = allData[i].Price.ToString();      g.transform.GetChild(4).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = allData[i].Icon;
            g.GetComponent<Button>().ManzellyAddEventListener(i,itemclicked);
        }

        Destroy(Tamplets);
    }
    
    IEnumerator GetData()
    {
        string url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1UU35G9Zx_7rCCM0xL7Qso_l3vhxgoIt0";

        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);

        request.chunkedTransfer = false;

        Loading.SetActive(true);

        yield return request.Send();

        if (request.isNetworkError) {  }
        else
        {
            if (request.isDone)
            {          
                allData = JsonHelper.GetArray<Data>(request.downloadHandler.text);
                StartCoroutine(GetIcon());
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator GetIcon()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < allData.Length; i++)
        {
            WWW w = new WWW(allData[i].IconUrl);

            Loading.SetActive(true);

            yield return w;

            if(w.error != null)
            {
                allData[i].Icon = defulticon;

                Loading.SetActive(false);
            }
            else
            {
                if (w.isDone)
                {
                    Texture2D tx = w.texture;

                    allData[i].Icon = Sprite.Create(tx, new Rect(0f, 0f, tx.width, tx.height), Vector2.zero, 10f);
                    Loading.SetActive(false);
                }
            }
        }

        DrawUI();
    }
}
```

I'm sorry guys about the code I just edit and make it simple to read...

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking .. your code format makes it quite hard to read tbh ... and you have quite strange constructs that I don't really understand .. for instance `ProductsPanel` could simply be `ProductPanel.SetActive(!ProductPanel.activeSelf);` same for the `Scrollme` .. then why mixing `UnityWebRequest.Get` with the obsolete `WWW`? `Total.text = Total.text;` what is this for?

Comment: In the `GetIcon` I personally would rather parallelize this and start individual parallel routines for each icon ... then in `Start` you already call `DrawUI` which depends on `allData` without a guarantee that the first web request already finished and that data is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I more or less understood your question now - you want the UI to be already filled before loading of all the icons is done.

For easier access I would begin with having a dedicated component on that template already referencing the correct components like e.g.

```
public class DataUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    [field: SerializeField] public Text NameText { get; private set; }
    [field: SerializeField] public Text DescText { get; private set; }
    [field: SerializeField] public Text PriceText { get; private set; }
    [field: SerializeField] public Image Image { get; private set; }
    [field: SerializeField] public Button Button { get; private set; }
}
```

And then I would do the following

```
public class Demo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Serializable]
    public struct Data
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Desc;
        public float Price;
        // don't need the sprite in here
        public string IconUrl;
    }

    [SerializeField] private Sprite defulticon;

    // this can eiher be a const or you could expose it in the Inspector if you want to adjust it later
    private const string url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1UU35G9Zx_7rCCM0xL7Qso_l3vhxgoIt0";

    // Yes, "Start" can return IEnumerator - in this case Unity will automatically run it as a Coroutine!
    private IEnumerator Start()
    {
        // you want to do this only once - otherwise you will have it blinking enabled and disabled all the time
        Loading.SetActive(true);

        using (var request = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
        {
            // these are both obsolete
            //request.chunkedTransfer = false;
            //yield return request.Send();

            yield return request.SendWebRequest();

            Loading.SetActive(false);

            if (request.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
            {
                // you should probably do something in case of an error and tell the user in the UI what went wrong!
                Debug.LogError($"Failed to load data! \n{request.error}"); 
                // TODO: UI
            }
            else
            {
                var allData = JsonHelper.GetArray<Data>(request.downloadHandler.text);
                FillUI(allData);
            }
        }
    }

    // spawns the entire UI with already available data at this point
    // for each icon starts a new individual and parallel loading routine
    private void FillUI(IList<Data> allData)
    {
        var template = GetComponentInChildren<DataUI>(true);

        for (var i = 0; i < allData.Count; i++)
        {
            var g = Instantiate(template, transform);
            // here now using the easier access through pre-assigned references
            g.NameText.text = allData[i].Name;
            g.DescText.text = allData[i].Desc;
            g.PriceText.text = allData[i].Price.ToString();
            var image = g.Image;

            // Here I would have a loading icon instead or even an animated loading icon via a different component
            //image.sprite = loadingSprite;
            g.Button.ManzellyAddEventListener(i, itemclicked);

            // Start parallel download
            StartCoroutine(GetIcon(allData[i].IconUrl, image));

            g.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }

        Destroy(template);
    }

    private IEnumerator GetIcon(string iconUrl, Image targetImage)
    { 
        // WWW is obsolete and you should use this instead
        using (var request = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(iconUrl))
        {
            yield return request.SendWebRequest();

            if (request.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
            {
                Debug.LogError($"Failed to load icon from {iconUrl}\n{request.error}", this);
                targetImage.sprite = defulticon;
                yield break;
            }

            var texture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)request.downloadHandler).texture;
            // adding a little check just in case the UI was  closed i the meantime
            if(targetImage) targetImage.sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0f, 0f, texture.width, texture.height), Vector2.zero, 10f);
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you rather want to not parallelize this an have each item spawning one by one you would only sightly change this to

```
    private IEnumerator Start()
    {
        Loading.SetActive(true);

        using (var request = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
        {
            yield return request.SendWebRequest();

            Loading.SetActive(false);

            if (request.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
            {
                // TODO: UI
                Debug.LogError($"Failed to load data! \n{request.error}");
                yield break;
            }
            else
            {
                var allData = JsonHelper.GetArray<Data>(request.downloadHandler.text);
                // you can yield another IEnumerator in order to run and await it
                yield return FillUI(allData);
            }
        }
    }

    // convert this into an IEnumerator as well so you can await it
    private IEnumerator FillUI(IList<Data> allData)
    {
        var template = GetComponentInChildren<DataUI>(true);

        for (var i = 0; i < allData.Count; i++)
        {
            var g = Instantiate(template, transform);
            // initially hide until loading of the icon is done
            g.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            g.NameText.text = allData[i].Name;
            g.DescText.text = allData[i].Desc;
            g.PriceText.text = allData[i].Price.ToString();
            var image = g.Image;
            //image.sprite = loadingSprite;
            g.Button.ManzellyAddEventListener(i, itemclicked);
            // this time await the icon loading
            yield return GetIcon(allData[i].IconUrl, image);

            g.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }

        Destroy(template);
    }

    private IEnumerator GetIcon(string iconUrl, Image targetImage)
    { 
        .. stays the same
    }
}
```

This time it will first load the current item's icon before spawning the next one. During the loading it stays hidden.